# vertical line between latex minipages

Tags: latex, markup

right now I have a latex section that looks like

```
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}   %left column
...
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth} %right column
...
\end{minipage}
```

This makes a nice looking two column layout, but I would like to add a vertical bar between the two minipages (where I currently have \hfill). What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using

```
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}   %left column

...

\end{minipage}

\hfill\vline\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth} %right column

...

\end{minipage}
```

Works without needing to change to parbox and staying with minipage.

Comment: When doing this, I have to make sure that there are no empty lines between the `\end{minipage}` and `\hfill\vline\hfill` and then `\begin{minipage}`

Answer (score 7):

If using `minipage` is not a necessity for you, you could easily use the `tabular` environment together with `parbox` to achieve the desired result:

```
\begin{tabular}{l | l}
\parbox{0.35\textwidth}{
left column content
}
&
\parbox{0.35\textwidth}{
right column content
}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: For this it would be better to use a `p{<len>}` column specification rather than `l` followed by a `\parbox`.